# Number Formatting in DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-2.7

How can I format a subset of a DataFrame according to a custom formatting logic?

**Before**:

|  | Country | Last | Previous | Abs. Change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | United States | 8.60 | 8.30 | 0.30 |
| 1 | Japan | 2.50 | 2.50 | 0.00 |
| 2 | China | 2.00 | 2.10 | -0.10 |
| 3 | United Kingdom | 9.10 | 9.00 | 0.10 |
| 4 | Euro Area | 8.10 | 7.40 | 0.70 |

**After**:

|  | Country | Last | Previous | Abs. Change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | United States | 8.6 | 8.3 | 30 bp |
| 1 | Japan | 2.5 | 2.5 | 0 bp |
| 2 | China | 2.0 | 2.1 | -10 bp |
| 3 | United Kingdom | 9.1 | 9.0 | 10 bp |
| 4 | Euro Area | 8.1 | 7.4 | 70 bp |

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I only managed to format the whole DataFrame using `pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.1f}'.format`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['United States', 'Japan','China','United Kingdom','Euro Area'],
                    'Last': [8.60, 2.50, 2.00, 9.10, 8.10],
                    'Previous': [8.30, 2.50, 2.10, 9.00, 7.40],
                    'Abs. Change': [0.30, 0.00, -0.10, 0.10, 0.70]})
```

1 decimal rounding

```
df[['Country', 'Last', 'Previous']] = df[['Country', 'Last', 'Previous']].round(1)
```

Add `bp`

```
df['Abs. Change'] = df['Abs. Change'].apply(lambda x: str(x) + ' bp')
```

Result

```
print(df)

         Country  Last  Previous Abs. Change
0   United States   8.6       8.3      0.3 bp
1           Japan   2.5       2.5      0.0 bp
2           China   2.0       2.1     -0.1 bp
3  United Kingdom   9.1       9.0      0.1 bp
4       Euro Area   8.1       7.4      0.7 bp
```

Comment: Thanks!
Had to change some of your code because the way my DataFrame is built returned values slightly inferior to what I wanted. Example: 29.9999999 instead of 30
`df['Abs. Change'] = df['Abs. Change'].apply(lambda x: f'{round(x,None)} bp')`

Answer (score 0):

**Original Data:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['United States', 'Japan','China','United Kingdom','Euro Area'],
                    'Last': [8.60, 2.50, 2.00, 9.10, 8.10],
                    'Previous': [8.30, 2.50, 2.10, 9.00, 7.40],
                    'Abs. Change': [0.30, 0.00, -0.10, 0.10, 0.70]})
```

Decimal 1:

```
import numpy as np
df=np.round(df, decimals = 1)
```

Add bp:

```
df['quantity'] = df['quantity'].apply(lambda x: x*100)
df['Abs. Change'] = df['Abs. Change'].apply(lambda x: str(x) + ' bp')
```

Result
[Resultant dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THWZa.png)